# Understanding SAS Read/Write Speeds

Tags: speed, sas

I very often hear SAS hard drives referred to as "6Gb/S".

[However, when looking at actual specifications](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/ultrastar-cheetah-sas,2004-6.html), the top benchmarks are in the 100s of MB/s.

[Right here](http://www.lmc.com.au/products/Hard_Disk_Drive_and_Enclosure/Seagate/572890/Seagate_Cheetah_300Gb_3.5inch_15.6K_rpm_16MB_SAS_%5BST3300657SS%5D), the spec for the Seagate Cheetah states `Interface: 6-Gb/s SAS`.

What is the difference here?

Comment: 6Gbit/s is the interface speed (maximum speed of the SAS interface). The actual drive data transfer speed is in the 100s of Mbyte/s range.

Comment: Ah. Interesting. So it's funny that drive specifications don't usually give an actual benchmark, just the RPM. Does that sound accurate?

Comment: It is a marketing gimmick to confuse the layman. If you want to know the real data rates of a drive, run it thru HD Tune. And focus also on the access time which is more important for the OS than the R/W speeds.

Comment: Ah. Tricky. So, is it accurate to say SSDs run between 400/500Mbps, meaning one purchased for $80.00 @ Walmart is literally 4x faster than your best SAS HDDs?

Comment: First, consumer ssd will usually run at 200-and-some MB/s. Second, that is the linear access speed, which is only half the story. The real ssd deal is in the random acces, where it's 10-30x faster than a hdd. The only reason not to go ssd is the price (if your server only supports SAS and not SATA, a SAS ssd is way more expensive)

Comment: @Dan Great and thanks. BTW, can you turn your first comment into an answer? You actually answered my question, Keltari didn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

6Gbit/s is the SAS interface speed, and not the actual harddrive speed (which is in the 100s of MBytes/s range, and that only if you are measuring the sequential transfer speed)

Answer (score 0):

You are misreading the form of measurement.  GB/s is giga*byte* per second.  Gb/s is giga*bit* per second.

There are 8 bits in a byte.

Comment: True. However even with this, 6 Gb/s would be ~750MB/s, which is about 5x faster than the benchmark on this drive (?).